# lua socket client

Tags: windows, sockets, lua

I am trying to make a simple lua socket client for the Socket Server example, from the Lua Socket page.

The server part works though, I tried it with telnet.

But the client part isn't working.

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 100
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
tcp:send("hello world");
```

It is only supposed to connect to it, send some data and receive some in return.

Can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your server is likely receiving per line. As noted in the [receive](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive) docs, this is the default receiving pattern. Try adding a newline to your client message. This completes the receive on the server:

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 100
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
--note the newline below
tcp:send("hello world\n");

while true do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then break end
end
tcp:close()
```

Comment: Alternatively, use a different `receive` pattern, e.g. `local threebytes = tcp:receive(3)`.