# LUA Script - web socket communication

Tags: lua, websocket, client-server, server-side

I am working with between Linux-based machine and android app.

First of all, I need to open a server socket on the machine to communicate with the app.

I need to code with LUA Script, and I have no idea with it..

Could you please give me some exmaple to open a server socket and receive the message from android app?

thank you.

Comment: no one knows maybe?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for websocket support in Lua, try [lua-websockets](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets).

For regular sockets, you can use luasocket; the [introduction](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/introduction.html) page includes an echo server example working over TCP; this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013290/lua-socket-client) includes a client example.