# Did anyone try to use websockets with Shiva3D?

Tags: lua, shiva3d

Did anyone try to use websockets with Shiva3D ?
I want to create communication between client and server and I think it is easier to use websockets than tcp, because overhead is not so big.
Is there already library for websockets or I can use c++ and bind to lua. I am totally new to lua.

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Answer (score 0):

Shiva3D does not let you 'require' external modules (probably security risk). Otherwise you could use lua-websockets on github, find it easily with google. It is mentioned in another SO post: [LUA Script - web socket communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897557/lua-script-web-socket-communication/16901718).

You can write [c++ plugin, which is then accessible from Lua](http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/doc/plugin/create) scripts. THis requires you have a Verisign certificate to sign the plugin. So if you have a favorite c++ library for websockets (wt, websockets++, etc) you can expose that to your Lua scripts.