# Sending serialized images over network in Lua

Tags: serialization, lua, love2d, luasocket

I am developing a little game in lua (using [love2D](http://love2d.org/)), and what I want to do is serialize an image in order to send it to another peer. So, I simple get the string [description of the image file](https://love2d.org/wiki/Data%3agetString), then I write it on the socket.

The problem is that nothing arrive to destination (neither with the loop-back address). I also tried to pass the string to the `print` function but, again, nothing happen.

How is it possible? What can I do?

Comment: Can you show some code? Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013290/lua-socket-client

Comment: I second that, Without code all we can do is guess randomly, and there's a lot of things that *could* be wrong.