# LuaSocket server:accept() timeout (TCP)

Tags: lua, luasocket

**Problem**

Following `LuaSocket` [Introduction](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/introduction.html) I managed to get the server running. I also managed to connect from the client side. I noticed, however, that the server script freezes until `server:accept()` gets the connection.

**Research**

`LuaSocket` [Reference](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout) specifies:

> Use the settimeout method or accept might block until another client shows up.

This is even included in the example code. However, `client:settimeout(10)` is called after `local client = server:accept()` so the script gets blocked before it reaches this point.

I read that this could be worked around by multithreading but this seems to be an exaggeration.

**Questions**

1. How do you cause the server script to stop waiting for connection and move on?
2. How do I guard from similar problems with `client:receive()` (server side) and `tcp:receive()` (client side) (or `client:settimeout(10)` takes care of that)?

**Code**

server (from `LuaSocket` [Introduction](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/introduction.html))

```
-- load namespace
local socket = require("socket")
-- create a TCP socket and bind it to the local host, at any port
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 0))
-- find out which port the OS chose for us
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
-- print a message informing what's up
print("Please telnet to localhost on port " .. port)
print("After connecting, you have 10s to enter a line to be echoed")
-- loop forever waiting for clients
while 1 do
  -- wait for a connection from any client
  local client = server:accept()
  -- make sure we don't block waiting for this client's line
  client:settimeout(10)
  -- receive the line
  local line, err = client:receive()
  -- if there was no error, send it back to the client
  if not err then client:send(line .. "\n") end
  -- done with client, close the object
  client:close()
end
```

client (follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9014261/6575359))

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 100
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
--note the newline below
tcp:send("hello world\n");

while true do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then break end
end
tcp:close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [server:timeout()](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout) before calling `server:accept()`:

```
server:settimeout(2)
local client, err = server:accept()
print(client, err)
```

This prints `nil timeout` for me if no request comes in 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but you can also call `client:settimeout()`. `server:settimeout` call is needed to set it for `accept`.