# Lua TCP/IP simple Client Server connection

Tags: tcp, lua, server, client

I'm looking for a simple client-server connection in Lua. Due to bad online documentation I'm quite helpless. I found two threads here in stackoverflow but they didn't help much. Here is what I have so far:

Client:

```
local socket = require("socket")
local host, port = "192.168.100.47", 51515
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
tcp:send("hello world\n");

while true do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then
      break
    end
end

tcp:close()
```

Server:

```
local socket = require("socket")
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 51515))
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

print(socket._VERSION)
print(tcp)

while 1 do

  local client = server:accept()

  line = client:receive()
  client:send("it works\n")

end
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to communicate between this two servers but I don't know how it works and I also can't find much in the internet. So the question is: how to write a simple TCP server and client with LUA?

Comment: What's the problem with the example you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working client/server example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445423/luasocket-serveraccept-timeout-tcp), which is based on [luasocket documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/introduction.html) and SO answers. If you have issues with getting it to work, you need to provide specific details about those issues.