# Communicate server port to client? (TCP)

Tags: tcp, lua, luasocket

**Problem**

Following `LuaSocket` [Introduction](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/introduction.html) I managed to get the `server` running. I also managed to connect from the `client` side. But to get this connection the `client` must know the `server` port number. In the example code the `server` port is 0, which means:

> If port is 0, the system automatically chooses an ephemeral port.

I guess this approach has it's advantages, but how does the poor `client` is supposed to know which port to connect to?

**Question**

How to communicate an ephemeral port number from `server` to `client`? I assume there should be no human action in the process.

**Code**

server (from `LuaSocket` [Introduction](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/introduction.html))

```
-- load namespace
local socket = require("socket")
-- create a TCP socket and bind it to the local host, at any port
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 0))
-- find out which port the OS chose for us
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
-- print a message informing what's up
print("Please telnet to localhost on port " .. port)
print("After connecting, you have 10s to enter a line to be echoed")
-- loop forever waiting for clients
while 1 do
  -- wait for a connection from any client
  local client = server:accept()
  -- make sure we don't block waiting for this client's line
  client:settimeout(10)
  -- receive the line
  local line, err = client:receive()
  -- if there was no error, send it back to the client
  if not err then client:send(line .. "\n") end
  -- done with client, close the object
  client:close()
end
```

client (follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9014261/6575359))

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 100
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
--note the newline below
tcp:send("hello world\n");

while true do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then break end
end
tcp:close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How to communicate an ephemeral port number from server to client? I assume there should be no human action in the process.I assume there should be no human action in the process.

You are right. The server example is quite odd. The servers generally should bind to specific port. It shouldn't be ephemeral. So that when the server restarts the client connects to the same port as earlier. Otherwise, the clients would be at loss if server ports keeps changing.

Clients, can indeed bind to ephemeral ports ( they generally do ). Servers should be bound to specific ones.

Comment: How do I choose a server port then? In other words how: do I make sure the port I choose is not used by another application? If I choose a port that is alreaby in use which aplication will have priority?

Comment: If one process binds to a specific IP:Port, any other process later shall fail in its attempt to bind to that specific IP:Port.

Answer (score 1):

In TCP/IP connections the server always BIND to a known port. A server is not allowed to bind to port 0. It has to be available on a known port so clients can connect to it. You should change the example to bind the server to a fixed port and then use that fixed port in the client connect function.

Comment: It is an example from the official `LuaSocket` - package authors - page. Misleading for begginers, I think.

Comment: Yes i know. I am using the package. The server MUST have a visible bind port.